# Generating pdf from latex

Tags: pdf, latex, pdflatex, lyx

I have been using two computers to generating pdf files from latex file by Winshell, but the characters (or images) in the pdf files generated from latex file on one computer looks always much more clear than the pdf pdf file generated by the same file on the other computer. Could anyone tell me what the problem is, or how to improve the quality of pdf file to be genearted on the other computer?  (The Adobe I am using on the two computers are on the same version)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to describe the difference in the setup of the two TeX environments. We're not psychics, and we don't have access to your computers!

Comment: are you sure the problem is with the output and not with the screen or something like that? Did you open the files generated by the two computers at the same time on the same computer?

Comment: Vivi, I am sure the problem is with the output, and I did see that there is a big difference between the quality of the pdf files generated by the two computers at the same time on the same screen.

Comment: Yuji, I use MikTek as the TeX environments on both computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an answer, but just a possibility.  Does the LaTeX document specify a specific font?  If so, it's possible that the font is available on only one of the computers and on the other it's reverting back to a default font that looks similar but is of lower quality.

This would be indicated in the log file.  Actually the log file is something you should check, anyway, since it may indicate some other difference that's causing the problem.  So I would do a diff of the log files on both computers to see what the differences are.

If it's a font substitution issue I would expect the documents to have some other subtle differences, e.g., fonts having slightly different widths and kerning so that the lines in the document break between different words, or a line in one document runs slightly longer than the same line in the other.

Also, if it's not just text, but also images, that are the problem, then it's not font substitution that's the problem. In that case comparing the LaTeX log files should reveal differences.a